# Android: Need to change the spinner background color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I'm using three spinners inside of my XML file. Want to change spinner color until press the next spinner.

This is my xml I used:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner13"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/mybg"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#0000FF" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner23"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/mybg"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#0000FF" />
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner33"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/mybg"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#0000FF"/>
```

and this is mybg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@style/AppBaseTheme.Yellow"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@style/AppBaseTheme.Yellow" />
</selector>
```

And Style :

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>
    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme.Yellow">
    <item name="android:background">#FFAA00</item>
</style> 
</resources>
```

Comment: You need to override the android style of spinner background and use this new theme in your app. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6705973/334522

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change mybg.xml as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFAA00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFAA00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

If want to show the arrow (">"). You can change your file mybg.xml as below.
The nine-patch file can be found in /Android/android-sdks/plataforms//data/res/spinner_default_holo_light.9.png. Copy this to your drawable folder.

File res/drawable/mybg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="transparent">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#AAFFAA00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#AAFFAA00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_default_holo_light"></item>
</layer-list>
```

File res/layout/activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:entries="@array/listX"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="119dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:entries="@array/listX"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="151dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:entries="@array/listX"/>
```

File MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3;


        sp1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        sp2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        sp3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

        Drawable d = sp1.getBackground();

        sp1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                sp1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybg);
                sp2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_default_holo_light);
                sp3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_default_holo_light);
                return false;
            }
        });

        sp2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                sp1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_default_holo_light);
                sp2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybg);
                sp3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_default_holo_light);
                return false;
            }
        });

        sp3.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                sp1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_default_holo_light);
                sp2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_default_holo_light);
                sp3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybg);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I just want to keep the color until other spinner selected.Actually I'm using 3 spinners.If i apply this background spinner shape was completely changing(not showing that ">" symbol @GBFSoft

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by Gustavo's answer, here is my version of Spinner's background with DropDown arrow. Just the complete background, not only the arrow.

This is how it looks

[image: Screenshot of Spinner using spinner_bg.xml]

Apply on spinner like

```
<Spinner
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg" />
```

spinner_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
<color android:color="@color/InputBg" />
</item>
<item android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:right="8dp">
<layer-list>
<item android:width="12dp" android:height="12dp" android:gravity="center" android:bottom="10dp">
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="45"
    android:toDegrees="45">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#666666" />
        <stroke android:color="#aaaaaa" android:width="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</rotate>
</item>
<item android:width="30dp" android:height="10dp" android:bottom="21dp" android:gravity="center">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/InputBg"/>
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

`@color/InputBg` should be replaced by the color you want as your background.

First it fills the background with desired color. Then a child layer-list makes a square and rotates it by 45 degrees and then a second Rectangle with background color covers the top part of rotated square making it look like a down arrow. (There is an extra stroke in rotated rectangle with is not really required)

Comment: Thanks it worked! Is there a way of making the corners of the spinner rounded?