# Unable to make background color of spinner in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want the background color of spinner Through programmatically but I didn't get.Here is my description of xml and .java file.

Step 1: This is my xml file for spinner.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/yourorder_form_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:weightSum="1" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

And in my .java file simple I have written

```
spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Android");
    list.add("Java");
    list.add("Spinner Data");
    list.add("Spinner Adapter");
    list.add("Spinner Example");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinner1.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF);
```

Here I am not getting any error and I am getting color of LinearLayout's background color only.

Comment: Show more code. How do you init spinner1?

Answer (score 0):

Add in xml spinner tag

```
            android:background="#color code"
```

like here edited code

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="#000000"
/>


<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="#232323"
/>
```

Comment: Through programmatically I want to acheive that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the spinners background color in xml like this:

```
android:background="YOUR_HEX_COLOR_CODE"
```

and if you use the drop down menu with you spinner you can set its background color like this:

```
android:popupBackground="YOUR_HEX_COLOR_CODE"
```

File

> res/drawable/mybg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="transparent">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#AAFFAA00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#AAFFAA00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"></item>
</layer-list>

sp1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                sp1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybg);
}
}
```

Comment: I want to acheive Through programmatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032594/android-need-to-change-the-spinner-background-color

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change programmatically just check your edited code

```
spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Android");
list.add("Java");
list.add("Spinner Data");
list.add("Spinner Adapter");
list.add("Spinner Example");

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
spinner1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```