# android spinner default drop down icon color change

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-xml

Here image of spinner . i want change spinner default drop down icon color.

[image: Here Image of spinner]

Comment: use custom spinner adapter

Comment: hey Refer This answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032594/android-need-to-change-the-spinner-background-color

Comment: @Prag's need to change icon color not background

Comment: you mean dropdown icon??

Comment: yes dropdown default icon

Comment: view my answer link will tell you how to deal with it..

Comment: that is for custom icon.. i am using default spinner dropdown icon. you can see left side of today text

Comment: what you want to do with it..........

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55423/discussion-between-prags-and-rizwan-ahmed).

Answer (score 1):

create a new XML file in the drawable folder(background.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/myspinner_select" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/myspinner_press" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/myspinner_press" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/myspinner_normal" />
</selector>
```

associate this Spinner drawable in your XML layout file

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner_chemical"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
         android:background="@drawable/background"/>
```

this may help you..

Answer (score 0):

You can set the spinners background color in xml like this:

```
android:background="YOUR_HEX_COLOR_CODE"
```

and if you use the drop down menu with you spinner you can set its background color like this:

```
android:popupBackground="YOUR_HEX_COLOR_CODE"
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13550512/3492139

Comment: Also you can refer : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032594/android-need-to-change-the-spinner-background-color>

Comment: i am talking about icon not background

Answer (score 0):

see this site is very helpful

> http://android-holo-colors.com/